# Ruby Split array for two with partition and with_index

Tags: arrays, ruby, enumerable, enumerator

Can you give explanation of logic or algorithm of ruby behaviour for this construction:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
arr.partition.with_index{|_,index| index>2}
```

How to formalize logic when iterate through Enumerable give 2 arrays output.
When we just call  single `partition` its clear - just method behavior, but when it trails by `with_index` this construction become "Magical" for me.

Thank you

UPD:  The condition is not in block of `partition`, it is in separate 'Enumerable' Object method block. This method is `with_index`.  **This second level of interaction is interesting for me**. Why do conditions of  `with_index` have influence on  partition result?  **This is a behavior that is not clear from `partition` documentation.**

Comment: What is magical for you here? Returns two arrays, the first containing the elements of the block evaluates to true, the second containing the rest(from [api doc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition)).

Comment: Alex Golubenko you tell me about single partition, I ask question about communication between partition and with_index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably read in the Ruby docs for `partition`:

> If no block is given, an enumerator is returned instead.

```
> arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
> arr.partition
=> #<Enumerator: ...>
```

You'll see the same thing in the description for a lot of the methods in [`Enumerable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html) but there isn't much detail about the enumerator that's returned.

The key to the enumerator chaining is in the the behaviour of the `each` method in the `Enumerator` that's returned. For example, the `Enumerator` returned by `partition` *has an `each` method that behaves like `partition`*. This is how you're able to pass a single block and get the combined behaviour of `partition` and `with_index`. If you do this in a couple of steps it might help:

```
> enumerator = arr.partition
=> #<Enumerator: ...>
> enumerator.each { |n| n < 3 } # just to demonstrate `each` performing a partition
=> [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]
> enumerator.with_index { |_, index| index > 2 }
=> [[4, 5], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Another way to think about it is that `partition` with no block given is like passing `:partition` to [`enum_for`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Object.html#method-i-enum_for) e.g.

```
> another_enum = arr.enum_for(:partition)
=> #<Enumerator: ...>
> another_enum.with_index { |_, index| index > 2 } # same result as above
=> [[4, 5], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: Great @DmitryDmitriev - glad it helped

Answer (score 1):

When the index is > 2 ruby create a new array with the rest of values

Answer (score 1):

**partition**

> Returns two arrays, the first containing the elements of enum for which the block evaluates to true, the second containing the rest.
>   If no block is given, an enumerator is returned instead.

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
arr.partition.with_index{|_,index| index>2} 
=> [[4, 5], [1, 2, 3]]
```

First array will contains `[4,5]` because it satisfys the condition `index > 2`.

Second array will contains all other elements: `[1,2,3]`

Comment: Condition is not in block of partition, it is in separate method block. This method is 'with_index'.  This second level of interaction is interesting for me. Why do conditions of  "witth_index" have influence on  partition result?  This is a behavior that is not clear from partition documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You are conflating the Enumerable module and the Enumerator class. All methods in the module Enumerable are instance methods that require their receiver to be an enumerator (an instance of the class Enumerator).

You use "include Enumerable" in your custom class and implement an each method which returns an enumerator:

```
def each
  return enum_for(:each) unless block_given?

  @apples.each { |apple| yield apple }
end
```

When a method contained in Enumerable is executed on an instance of a class that includes Enumerable, Ruby inserts the method each IMPLICITLY between the instance and the Enumerable method.

with_index is NOT a method of Enumerable module. It is an instance method of the Enumerator class. Now remember I stated that when you include Enumerable module in your custom class and implement an each method, that each method can be used to return an enumerator instance. So, classes that have a method each that returns an enumerator can make use of the method Enumerator#with_index by (explicitly) inserting each between an instance of the class and with_index. Or it can invoke with_index on the enumerable module method since that returns an enumerator instance:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
arr.partition.with_index{|_,index| index>2}
```

In the above example, partition is an instance method of Enumerable module and with_index is an instance method of Enumerator class. partition returns an enumerator instance which can take with_index.

Now for understanding what this statement does, you can simply look at the Enumerable docs which explains what partition does:

Returns two arrays, the first containing the elements of enum for which the block evaluates to true, the second containing the rest.

So in your case, it is determining whether the index is greater than 2. If it is, it gets put in one array, otherwise the other.

Comment: "All methods in the module Enumerable are instance methods that require their receiver to be an enumerator" Nope. Enumerable only requires that the including class implement an `#each` instance method.

Comment: ...and `#each` _may_ return an Enumerator when no block is given, but it's not strictly required.

Comment: @mwp can you cite an instance when NOT returning an Enumerator would be practical? Think about what those methods in module Enumerable do. For example: reduce invokes the each method and expects that each method to allow it to enumerate over values in order to build an accumulation. If each was not an Enumerator, then how could methods like reduce do their work?